# How do i handle issue with GNU GRUB?

Tags: grub2

What happened is that i was trying to install gfsview on ubuntu 12.04, for that it was asking for dependencies like libgtk etc. When i did install for dependencies it asked for ifupdown and as i was getting instructions on terminal i followed. After doing sudo apt-get install ifupdown , Ubunut software center disappeared and even if i try to click on any app on left side it doesn't open. I did restart from cpu and what i get this window:

```
GNU GRUB version 1.99-2ubuntu3.19

Ubuntu , with linux 3.11.0-26-generic
Ubuntu , with linux 3.11.0-26-generic(recovery mode)
Previous linux version
memory test
memory test(serial console)
```

i don't what i do?

Comment: Strange, `ifupdown` shouldn't break GRUB.

Comment: Try choosing the first option (highlight, then `Enter`)

Comment: This is just the normal boot menu for Ubuntu. As Bhardwaj Raju said. You just need to highlight the first entry and press enter. That should get you back into your normal boot. If this works you can fix it if you don't want the menu to show up every boot. You can make it so it boots directly to the first entry. Look up `Grub Customizer` It is a graphical interface that is easy to use to set up Grub the way you want.

Comment: Or just wait 10 seconds (Or was it 5?)

Comment: yes ,i used the first option and hit enter but get a black window(some numeric written on it). After getting this nothing happens. Even i press any key it doesn't work , just at standstill position. Not only first option i did with all 4 options. Plz help me , i need to save data. I am not from computer science background. I use ubuntu only as working platform.

Answer (score 0):

That is just the standard boot menu. It is used to

- Boot other operating systems (doesn't apply in your case, since you only have Ubuntu)
- Boot into recovery mode
- Boot into RAM testing (`memtest86+`)
- Boot from other kernels

Now, all you have to do is hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: yes ,i used the first option and hit enter but get a black window(some numeric written on it). After getting this nothing happens. Even i press any key it doesn't work , just at standstill position. Not only first option i did with all 4 options. Plz help me , i need to save data. I am not from computer science background. I use ubuntu only as working platform.

Comment: Can you post the exact message? A photo of the screen when this happens, maybe?